# Basic Java - Please help a stressed noob with a method?

Tags: java

My name's Ali, I have just started two units of study with the Open University, so I am entirely fresh-faced to Java. I am trying to get the following code to compile but the lack of support i'm getting from my tutor is horrendous and the several books I have splayed out across my room aren't helping me get going.

I have been given a method that I wish to answer some questions about:

```
public char[] methodA()
{
    char[] alphas = {'s', 't', 'e', 'a', 'm'};
    char temp = alphas[0];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < alphas.length - 1)//1
    {
        alphas[i] = alphas[i+1]; //2
        i++;
    }

    alphas[alphas.length-1]=temp;

    return alphas;
}
```

How do I get this to compile successfully using my IDE? I have tried just enclosing it within the syntax for my 'main' method but it's not accepting it.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
package openuniversity;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        public static char[] methodA()
        {   
            char[] alphas = {'s', 't', 'e', 'a', 'm'};
            char temp = alphas[0];
            int i = 0;

            while (i < alphas.length - 1)//1
            {
                alphas[i] = alphas[i+1]; //2
                i++;
            }

            alphas[alphas.length-1]=temp;

            return alphas;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.
Ali

Comment: Please tell us which IDE you are using. Also, considering this is java, please post the whole class code.

Comment: You can't simply declare method inside another method. Read carefully the answers.. CAREFULLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods must be enclosed within a class.  If your IDE has already generated that for you, then you should be able to make it a sibling of your main method, as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your main method code goes here
    }

    public char[] methodA() {
        char[] alphas = {'s', 't', 'e', 'a', 'm'};
        char temp = alphas[0];
        int i = 0;

        while (i < alphas.length - 1)//1
        {
            alphas[i] = alphas[i+1]; //2
            i++;
        }

        alphas[alphas.length-1]=temp;
        return alphas;
    }
}
```

If you wish to call `methodA` from your main method, you will either need to:

- Create a new object of type `Foo` (by saying `Foo x = new Foo()`)
  then invoke the method on the object you create (by saying
  `x.methodA()`)
- Change `methodA` to be static, by changing its signature to `public
  static char[] methodA()`, then invoke the method statically (by saying `Foo.methodA()`)

Comment: I feel extremelly stupid now. I had my methodA as part of the main method. I just closed off the main method and it worked. Many thanks!!

Comment: How would I go about displaying the results of invoking the method? :S

Comment: You can print things to the console by using `System.out.print("my text here")`.  `System.out.print` takes a `String`, so you will need to create a `String` from your `char[]` by saying `new String(Foo.methodA())`.  So the whole thing would be `System.out.print(new String(Foo.methodA()))`.  Note that there is also `System.out.println("my text here")`, which will automatically append a newline character to the end of the `String` you've provided, for a (potentially) cleaner output.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to call it within `public static void main(String [] args)`, if it's situated in the same class where `main` is, you should declare method as `static`.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       methodA();
    }

    public static char[] methodA(){
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first: On Java, methods are always inside a class, including the `main`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is the main method, this is invoked when
        //you execute the compiled class on your IDE
        methodA();
    }

    public static char[] methodA() {
        // Insert your logic here
    } 
}
```

See how I've changed `methodA` to be `static`? That's because static methods can only access other static methods, variables or constants. If you don't want it to be static, you can do:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is the main method, this is invoked when
        //you execute the compiled class on your IDE
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.methodA();
    }

    public char[] methodA() {
        // Insert your logic here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a method into another method in Java, all methods are inside of the class at same level, but (i repeat) you cannot put a method inside another.
an general example:

```
public class MyClass{
      public static void main (String[]args){//main method
      }
      public static void method1(){
        //method corpse
      }
      public static int method2(int x){
        //method corpse
      }
      public static char[] methodA(){
        //method corpse
      }
}
```